# C# AES encrypt to java 8 decrypt

Tags: java, c#, encryption, aes

I'm trying to mimic a java encryption routine in C# because the endpoint is java based and will be decrypting the value generated by C#.

I've tried different implementations using `AesCryptoServiceProvider` and `AesManaged` from several examples found in SO and around the web but I still can't get the java endpoint to successfully decrypt the value, it errors with `{"message":"AUTHENTICATION_ERROR: Error while decrypting the cipher.","status":"Error"}`.

Using postman I was able to call the java endpoint and retrieve a document using the
encrypted text generated by the java code posted below, so that part is positively verified.

The endpoint uses the header values to decrypt the text and verify the contents, here are the pertinent code pieces:

#### java encryption

```
  private static Cipher generateCipher(int mode, String password, String salt, String iv, Integer iterations, Integer keySize) throws Exception {
    byte[] saltBytes = salt.getBytes("UTF-8"); byte[]ivBytes = iv.getBytes("UTF-8");
    // Derive the key
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), saltBytes, iterations, keySize);

    SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
    //encrypt the message
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); cipher.init(mode, secret, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));
    return cipher;
  }

  public static String AES_encrypt(String plainText, String password, String salt, String iv, Integer iterations, Integer keySize) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = generateCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, password, salt, iv, iterations, keySize);
    byte[] encryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
    return encoder.encodeToString(encryptedTextBytes);
  }
```

#### headers

```
  interface_name: interfaceName  
  strength: 256  
  salt: salt_sixteen1234  
  iterate: 100  
  iv: sixteen_value_12  
  ciphertext: ECtKO7VluxCPFS/D8LVsb2bOQjhViIZm+O3zfMqSwJOLLTpDL4xdgwmIWr+41n5j
```

#### C# encrypt

```
  ...
   using (var csp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
   {
          ICryptoTransform e = GetCryptoTransform(csp, true, key, salt, iv);
          byte[] inputBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
          byte[] output = e.TransformFinalBlock(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length);
         string encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(output);

        return encrypted;
   }
  ...

   private static ICryptoTransform GetCryptoTransform(AesCryptoServiceProvider csp, bool encrypting, string password, string salt, string iv, int iterations)
   {
        csp.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        csp.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        var spec = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt), iterations);
        byte[] key = spec.GetBytes(16);

        csp.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iv);
        csp.Key = key;
        if (encrypting)
        {
            return csp.CreateEncryptor();
        }
        return csp.CreateDecryptor();
   }
```

Comment: How do you pass the IV? It is typically prepended to the message, I cannot see that it is done.

Comment: @JonasH: it looks like as a static iv is in place so no need to pass the iv. B.t.w. **the usage of a static iv and salt is UNSECURE.**

Comment: You possibly use different key sizes (and thus AES variants). The Java code applies a `keySize` bits key (and if `strength` equals `keySize` a 256 bits key), the C# code a 128 bits key. Therefore, in the C# code in `GetCryptoTransform()` you should also pass the `keySize` parameter and determine the key in that method with `byte[] key = spec.GetBytes(keySize / 8);`. By the way: In the posted C# code the `iterations` parameter is missing in the `GetCryptoTransform` call. In addition, the `iterations` parameter is generally too small with 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test any C# encryption I added a decryption method to your Java code and run successfully a full round (encryption and decryption).

For the C# part I was too lazy to check your code (as @Topaco did it) and used my own code with your credentials to get an output that you can present to the Java decryption method.

Let's start with a longer **Security warning: the codes are using a static initialization vector and a static salt and the iteration count
for PBKDF2 key derivation is much too low (a minimum of 10.000 should be used)**. The codes do not have any exception handling and are for educational purpose only.

Running the C#-code gives a short output:

```
AES CBC 256 string encryption with PBKDF2 SHA1 key derivation
plaintext:      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
ciphertext:     5HMLSQKEgG+RADgPmf5Eyw0F/GG9sXFuWiHeuZxgpmJP+UoH4MZlvnQDrgnofQy4
```

Presenting the ciphertext to the Java decryption will give this output:

```
C# AES encrypt to java 8 decrypt
plaintext: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
ciphertext: 5HMLSQKEgG+RADgPmf5Eyw0F/GG9sXFuWiHeuZxgpmJP+UoH4MZlvnQDrgnofQy4
decryptedtext: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

decryption of a ciphertext from C#
ciphertextFromCsharp: 5HMLSQKEgG+RADgPmf5Eyw0F/GG9sXFuWiHeuZxgpmJP+UoH4MZlvnQDrgnofQy4
decryptedtextFromCsharp: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Both codes are available for a live self test here (Java: https://repl.it/@javacrypto/JavaAes256EncryptionWithPBKDF2SHA1keyderivation, C#: https://repl.it/@javacrypto/CsharpAes256Pbkdf2Encryption#main.cs).

C#-code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine("AES CBC 256 string encryption with PBKDF2 SHA1 key derivation");
        // credentials
    string plaintext = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
        string password = "myPassword";
    string saltString = "salt_sixteen1234";
    var iterationsCount = 100;
    string ivString = "sixteen_value_12";

    Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF8;
        byte[] saltBytes = enc.GetBytes(saltString);
    byte[] iv = enc.GetBytes(ivString);
    byte[] key;

        try {
      // pbkdf2 sha1 key derivation
      using (var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(
            password,
            saltBytes,
            iterationsCount,
            HashAlgorithmName.SHA1))
          {
            key = pbkdf2.GetBytes(32);
          }
            Console.WriteLine("plaintext:      {0}", plaintext);
            string ciphertext = encrypt(key, iv, plaintext);
            Console.WriteLine("ciphertext:     {0}", ciphertext);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
        }
    }

    static string encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] IV, string data) {
        byte[] encrypted;
        using(Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create()) {
            aesAlg.Key = key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;
            aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
            // create the streams used for encryption.
            using(var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream()) {
                using(var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
                    using(var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt)) {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(data);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
    }
}
```

Java-code:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("C# AES encrypt to java 8 decrypt");

        String plaintext = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
        String password = "myPassword";
        String iv = "sixteen_value_12";
        String salt = "salt_sixteen1234";
        int iterations = 100;
        int keySize = 256;
        System.out.println("plaintext: " + plaintext);
        String ciphertext = AES_encrypt(plaintext, password, salt, iv, iterations, keySize);
        System.out.println("ciphertext: " + ciphertext);
        String decryptedtext = AES_decrypt(ciphertext, password, salt, iv, iterations, keySize);
        System.out.println("decryptedtext: " + decryptedtext);
        System.out.println("\ndecryption of a ciphertext from C#");
        String ciphertextFromCsharp = "5HMLSQKEgG+RADgPmf5Eyw0F/GG9sXFuWiHeuZxgpmJP+UoH4MZlvnQDrgnofQy4";
        System.out.println("ciphertextFromCsharp: " + ciphertextFromCsharp);
        String decryptedtextFromCsharp = AES_decrypt(ciphertextFromCsharp, password, salt, iv, iterations, keySize);
        System.out.println("decryptedtextFromCsharp: " + decryptedtextFromCsharp);
   }

    private static Cipher generateCipher(int mode, String password, String salt, String iv, Integer iterations, Integer keySize) throws Exception {
        byte[] saltBytes = salt.getBytes("UTF-8"); byte[]ivBytes = iv.getBytes("UTF-8");
        // Derive the key
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), saltBytes, iterations, keySize);
        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
        //encrypt the message
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); cipher.init(mode, secret, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));
        return cipher;
    }

    public static String AES_encrypt(String plainText, String password, String salt, String iv, Integer iterations, Integer keySize) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = generateCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, password, salt, iv, iterations, keySize);
        byte[] encryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
        return encoder.encodeToString(encryptedTextBytes);
    }

    public static String AES_decrypt(String cipherText, String password, String salt, String iv, Integer iterations, Integer keySize) throws Exception {
        Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
        Cipher cipher = generateCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, password, salt, iv, iterations, keySize);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(decoder.decode(cipherText)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}
```